# Generate json file from PHP trouble special characters

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I have a special issue. I am trying to generate a json file to use as my translation file in side Unity3D.

I am doing it like this:

```
$lang = $_GET["lang"];

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=da.json');
header('Content-type: text/plain');

$jsonString = "{\n";

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ReloadedSnippets ORDER BY id");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $snippetId = $row['id'];

    $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ReloadedTranslations WHERE fk_snipId=$snippetId AND lang='$lang'");
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);

    $string1 = $row1["translation"];
    $string1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$string1);
    $jsonString .= "   ";
    $jsonString .= '"'.$row['snippet'].'": "'.$string1.'",';
    $jsonString .= "\n";

}

$jsonString .= '}';

$jsonString = mb_convert_encoding($jsonString,'utf-8','iso-8859-1');

echo $jsonString;
```

It actually does the job correct, but... When opening the file in sublimeText I see some weird insert just before special characters like the danish "æ ø å".

[image]

Can anyone explain what this is and if I should be concerned? And best of all... How do I get around this.

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: Why wouldn't you use built-in way `json_encode()` instead of generating JSON by yourself? This way will make JSON escaped.

Answer (score 2):

While you can certainly generate JSON by-hand I advise to instead using the built-in `json_encode` php function (see [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)). That function will take care of eventual characters that must be escaped like quotes.

Instead of generating directly the json string you generate an object representation and then convert it to string:

```
$jsonData = [];
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM ReloadedSnippets ORDER BY id");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $snippetId = $row['id'];

    $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ReloadedTranslations WHERE fk_snipId=$snippetId AND lang='$lang'");
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);

    $string1 = $row1["translation"];
    $string1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$string1);
    $jsonData[$row['snippet']] = $string1;
}

$jsonString = json_encode($jsonData);
echo $jsonString;
```

Comment: Well, tried this, but whenever a string has a special character (æøå) it comes out as "null". I agree that this would be the best solution, but I do not know how to make it work:-/

Comment: @Mansa It looks like there are some unencodable characters inside the input text or those characters are already written in the db. Maybe you can try to use `mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8")` to force utf8 mysql connection.

Comment: OK, done everything right now... Its all from beginning to end "utf8" but still the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change :

```
$jsonString = mb_convert_encoding($jsonString,'UTF-8',mb_detect_encoding($jsonString));
```

and add header

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```